# Node.TEXT_NODE and IE7

Tags: dom, internet-explorer-7, standards, w3c

I've some javascript that tests DOM node types against like this:

```
        if(node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
```

Of course, it all works fine in Firefox, Safari, and Opera. But Internet Explorer 7 is complaining that `Node` (with the capital N) is undefined. But that's part of [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/idl-definitions.html)!

Do I really need to change my code to use magic numbers? Or am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately you are not missing anything.

There is no Node constant in IE. Look here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-matters41.html at section "What else can you do with the DOM?".

So either you define your own Node constant or you simply ask for

```
node.nodeType === 3
```