# is it possible to remove an html comment from dom using jquery

Tags: jquery

just wondering if there was a way to remove an html comment using jquery.

```
<!-- <div id="main">Some text </div> -->
```

thanks

Comment: Although it can be removed from the DOM, as far as I can find you cannot hide it from people who use the "view source" menu option in their browsers. You should really do this using server-side scripting.

Answer (score 45):

Try this:

```
$('*').contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** This removes the elements from the DOM. Browsers often store a copy of the original page source that is accessible through a menu item. This doesn't get updated.

If you want to hide your comments, you could always insert your entire HTML markup (with comments) into the DOM using javascript. The javascript could, of course, be viewed, but it is a step removed from the first place people would look.

Comment: @Sinan - Works for me in Firefox 3.5.8 for Mac. I updated the code from my original version to use `*` instead of `body`, as it wasn't getting comments embedded within descendants of `body`.

Comment: @Sinan - Well, I guess it will depend on how you are viewing the source. Using Firebug, they are being removed, but the source that is retrieved using the 'Page Source' menu item never gets updated. It is always in its original state.

Comment: @Patrick, I checked my FF now, it's also 3.5.8, sorry i thought it was 3.6 and i'm also on a Mac, anyway i think my firebug doesn't give me proper results. As you say page source doesn't update once loaded, and  my firebug doesn't show any HTML comments, so i can't know if comment is removed or not.

Comment: @Sinan - You can make FF show comments by clicking on the small black triangle in the HTML tab, and select 'Show Comments'. Or, if you're using Safari (or perhaps OmniWeb like I do) you can right click anywhere on the page and click "Inspect Element". Safari's developer tools seems to show comments by default.

Comment: _approved_ it works, after activating comments on firebug i was able to see the results, however looping through all elements is a heavy operation not recommended.

Comment: @Sinan - Yeah, this was just a quick proof of concept. Would be better to limit to the specific areas where the unwanted comments reside.

Comment: Suggestion: Wouldn't `this.nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE` be more descriptive/readable code?

Comment: @MadsHansen If you are supporting IE7, notice that IE7 does not have Node constant defined http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423599/node-text-node-and-ie7

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. But I don't understand what the use of it would be. A comment will only be seen if you view the pagesource, and most (if not all) browsers that have a view source option will by default give you the source before javascript loading.

Comment: @user113716, you're missing the whole point Jasper is making. The comments are only removed when looking at the live page via a DOM inspector. If someone right-clicks on page and selects "View source" they will see the comments, because `javascript` is not run when viewing source. So if you're thinking about using the above method to hide sensitive information, think again.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a slightly hacky way, but it worked an absolute treat for me.

It makes use of the split() function.

Firstly

```
codeWithComments = $("*yourelementhere*").html();
var withoutComments = codeWithComments.split('-->');
$("*yourelementhere*").html(withoutComments[withoutComments.length-1]);
```

This will replace the HTML of the given element with the code directly after the last '-->' this of course assumes that you only have one set of comments in the given element. You could split on the last line of the comment to get an exact match.

Worked for me, might not work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the errors with when script tried to access an IFrame content.
Here is a modified version which is skipping IFrames:

```
$('*')
.filter((idx, el) => !(el instanceof HTMLIFrameElement))
.contents()
.each(() => {
    try {
        if(this.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -8):

I'm almost certain comments aren't actually part of the DOM.  They're part of the original HTML code, but when browsers convert it to the DOM, they get stripped as they serve no purpose for rendering.