# counting number of characters in a string but want to skip the comments

Tags: jquery

I wanted to count number of characters in a string which I pull from div tag like this:

```
$(".welcome-msg").html().length;
```

However it's counting HTML comments as characters inside the tag. So when I would like the result to be 0 I get 99 because of those comments and I don't have a way of telling if comments are dynamic or not. Is there an easy way to make sure comments are not counted? Or do I have to write regular expression for that?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried using `text()` instead? Or do you need the string to include the html elements and such..?

Comment: No, there's not an easy way to do that.  You need an HTML parser.  You can't use regular expressions to parse HTML because HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: Thanks David - it works. @Dan A. Yes I can - I am using jquery and html is just a string in this context.

Comment: David brings up a good point, if you want to strip any HTML tags, text() would be an easy way to do it.

Comment: @bobek, for the record: it is not a matter of HTML being a string or not.

Comment: @bobek are you looking for actual text length or html length without comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myhtml = $(".welcome-msg").html();
myhtml = myhtml.replace(/<!--.*?-->/sg, ""); 
myhtml.length();
```

regex from here [StackOverflow: Remove HTML comments with Regex, in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653207/remove-html-comments-with-regex-in-javascript)

Comment: -1 Why `replace` and not just `.text()`. Seems like overkill.

Comment: This seems oversimplified to me.  What about this as an example: <input value="<!--"><p>Here's some text I want to not be stripped</p><input value="-->">

Comment: @DanA. are you being sarcastic?

Comment: @iambriansreed Why do you think I'm being sarcastic?  I'm just trying to point out a pitfall of trying to parse HTML with regular expressions.  If you're looking for the definitive (and sarcastic) answer to this, look no further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: bobek asked about html comments inside a div. Sure .text() is more obvious, but this is a method that would work to do what he's asking. DanA. your comment isn't helpful and improbable, and doesn't address the problem. Why don't you offer a helpful solution, instead of criticizing those who are?

Comment: @alightd i have to agree with DanA, because improbable is not good enough and hes being helpful by pointing it out. But, did you get a downvote or something?

Comment: @alightd I never meant to criticize.  I totally agree that your solution would work most of the time.  However, if I can construct an example (regardless of how improbably it may be) where your answer fails, I think it's helpful for educational purposes to do so.  Also, I'm endorsing the nodeType solution proposed by d_inevitable, so I am not adding my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter comments out, but it is not easy. I will show you how you can filter them on the first level, which is easy, but if they are nested within other tags, then you need to do additional logic.

The key is to `.contents()` to get all the nodes within. This includes comment nodes. Then you can filter the comment nodes out by comapring against [nodeType](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/nodeType).

So it would be something like this:

```
$(".welcome-msg").contents().filter(function() { 
  return this.nodeType != 8;
}).appendTo("<div>").parent().html();
```

That will work for

```
<div class=".welcome-msg">
   <!--Comment --><span>hello</span>
</div>
```

But not for

```
<div class=".welcome-msg">
    <span><!--Comment -->hello </span> world 
</div>
```

You would need to iterate through all tags recursively and then it will work for everything.

With regular expressions you would need to be careful about `<script>` tags and `<style>` tags.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xYR5p/)

### Update (Recursive filter)

Doing it recursively is actually quite easy:

http://jsfiddle.net/xYR5p/3/

Made an entire plugin for it:

```
$.fn.removeComments = function() {
    this.contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 8;  
    }).remove();
    
    this.children().each(function() {
       $(this).removeComments(); 
    });
    
    return this;
};


console.log($(".welcome-msg").clone().removeComments().html());​
```