# How to get rid of "compressed/chunk" comment at the bottom of PHP pages?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using Javascript to do a GET request on a php page, but when I try to parse the php page as JSON, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I imagine because at the bottom of the PHP page, the following comment exists:

```
<!-- url here compressed/chunked Tue Sep  4 17:15:42 PDT 2012 -->
```

Comment: I don't recall seeing this phenomenon before. What causes this comment to happen?

Comment: "PHP page" is confusing. Pages are in HTML, that can be generated by your PHP script, and sent as a HTTP response to your HTTP request. So when you try to parse it in Javascript, it doesn't matter how the response was generated. This shouldn't be tagged as 'php'.

Comment: Well, due to the nature of the question, I think it might be ssome specific PHP + web server configuration that adds the comment the O.P. asks about. I would tend to re-insert `php` as a tag, even if to migrate the question to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment in the PHP file is a HTML comment and should not be sent within a JSON response (it  should only contain plain JSON)

You can either

a) remove the comment from the PHP file completely or

b) put it within a PHP section (using PHP-style comments)

```
<?php /* url here compressed/chunked Tue Sep  4 17:15:42 PDT 2012 */ ?>

<?php
// url here compressed/chunked Tue Sep  4 17:15:42 PDT 2012
?>
```

I don't think, you'll need this information in the JSON, do you?

Comment: I think that "how to remove" said comment is exactly what the O.P. asks for - and it does not look like it is explicit in his PHP source file.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have no control over the data provider. Also, it is poor form to put HTML comments in a json response. Any meta definitions like that should be in the actual header information.

In JS just split the string at the index of

```
function(data){

      var jsonString = data.substring( 0, data.indexOf("<!"));    
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse( jsonString);

}
```

In the case of < being a valid character in the data, do a regex for HTML comments. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653207/remove-html-comments-with-regex-in-javascript) post.

Comment: But what if the JSON legitimately contains `<`?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to another post on simply doing a regex to remove HTML comments.