# Sveltekit: how to remove HTML comments from app.html in production build?

Tags: sveltekit

I would like to strip HTML comments of app.html in my Sveltekit prduction build (and keep them in app.html during development), how to do it ?

The only thing I thought of would be an end-build step with some regex like described in [Remove HTML and Javascript comments automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600129/remove-html-and-javascript-comments-automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use env variables + hooks.server.js file

1: In your .env.development and/or env.preview

```
PUBLIC_ENV=development
```

2: In your hooks.server.js, override the html ( similar php/.net outputbuffer filter hooks )

```
import { PUBLIC_ENV } from '$env/static/public';

const outputbuffer = ( html ) =>
{

    // DO YOU WORK HERE TO ALTER THE HTML STRING

    return html;
}

export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => 
{
   let response = await resolve( event, 
   {
     transformPageChunk: async ({ html }) => 
     {
       if ( PUBLIC_ENV !== 'production' ) return outputbuffer( html );
     }
   });

   return response;
}
```