# Read HTML Comments with JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, comments

Is it possible to read a comment written in HTML?
I guess comments do not form part of the DOM therefore selecting them or evening assigning classes or id's might not be an option.

Is there any way to like read the content of the body and obtain an array of comments or something like that? Jquery is ok.

I want to create a plugin or function to do something like this:

```
<!-- top -->
<div>top stuff</div>

<!-- Content -->
<div>content stuff</div>

<script>

   var comments = $('body').getComments();
   alert(comments[0]); //returns "top"
   alert(comments[1]); //return "Content"
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look a this: [Get text inside HTML comment tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753384/get-text-inside-html-comment-tag) But I don't know if you may have problems in older IE (I think there was something about it, but I don't find any thing right now that would proof that)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use following snippet:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hErbL/1/)

```
$.fn.getComments = function () {
    return this.contents().map(function () {
        if (this.nodeType === 8) return this.nodeValue;
    }).get();
}
```

Comment: Nice, swift piece! Just tried this variation of your answer `alert($('body').getComments()[0])`, `alert($('body').getComments()[1])`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the output of my Firebug console:

```
>>> document.body.innerHTML = '<!-- comment -->';
"<!-- comment -->"

>>> document.body.childNodes
NodeList[Comment { data=" comment ", length=9, nodeType=8, more...}]

>>> document.body.childNodes[0]
Comment { data=" comment ", length=9, nodeType=8, more...}

>>> document.body.childNodes[0].data
" comment "
```

In short, JavaScript's DOM will pick up comments just as any other tags. They will be of type `Comment`. You can look up their `data` property to get the comment contents.

[EDIT]

I haven't checked this in any browsers other than Firefox 26; you might want to investigate a bit.