# Most efficient way to strip comments from a string javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am looking for an efficient way to strip HTML comments from a string representation of HTML:

```
<div>
  <!-- remove this -->
  <ul>
    <!-- and this -->
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I do not want to convert the string to actual nodes, the content is originally a string and the filesize is around 600mb.

Curious if anyone has had this problem before and found an efficient, and easily generalized solution.

Comment: Regular expressions acceptable?

Comment: absolutely, preferred

Comment: If you don't have nasty markup like `<div title="z<!--this is not"><div title="a comment-->zz">` (notice, though, this **is** valid HTML) then regexes are acceptable, as comments are not nestable (`<!-- <!-- -->` is the "same" as `<!-- <!-- --> -->`). If you do, or if you are afraid you might, among other reasons, then consider a broader tool, like a parser.

Comment: @acdcjunior `<!-- <!-- --> -->` is **not** the same as `<!-- <!-- -->`. The first parses too `{ignored} -->`, the second parses as `{ignored}` where `{ignored}` is the part the HTML parser ignores. This is precicely because comments are **not** nestable.

Comment: @dtech You are right. I expressed myself wrongly. I meant the initial part was the same. Meaning the second `-->` would not be a part of the comment, just as you said, so the regexes wouldn't have to mind nesting. (Edit: It does not matter now, I just tested, `<!-- aa <!-- aa -->` is **not valid HTML** as I predicted. It yields the error ***The document is not mappable to XML 1.0 due to two consecutive hyphens in a comment.*** in the second `--`, meaning two hyphens inside a comment are only allowed to close it, nothing else.)

Comment: I don't think your gonna be able to reasonably treat a 600mb string without lag & memory problems.

Comment: Would you suggest a technique for achieving this on a 600mb file?

Comment: At which file size would you say that lag and memory problems would occur when modifying a string in this way?

Comment: I ask because I can separate the file into smaller files no problem. I'm just looking for an efficient solution

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5654032/2100709

html = html.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g, "")

Comment: @TaylorMac To use regexes, you'll have to make several assumptions about the file (it is valid HTML + there are no `<div title="z<!--this is not a comment-">` + the others suggested in the link by @mwein). Even with a parser, you'd have to know how it deals with invalid HTML. Why JavaScript, tho?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming the variable `s` represents your html string, a RexExp replace as follows should work just fine.

```
s = s.replace(/<!--[\s\S]+?-->/g,"");
```

Variable `s` should now have comments removed.

Comment: Will test, although I am sure this is likely the best solution

Comment: Be aware of the gotcha that of `--` inside HTML comments are "forbidden" according to MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment#Specification but are allowed by the spec though it makes a note that some tools may not allow them. This trips me up when I occasionally try and comment out `script` tags

Comment: the ban on "--" is for XML documents, not HTML documents. read your link again.