# Python - HTML Comment is not serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization

I am trying to parse html page and save in a database. Creating json with tags of the page.

Some of the tags include javascript like

```
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("search.js", "");</script><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" defer="defer">
<!--
function SearchEnsureSOD() { EnsureScript('search.js',typeof(GoSearch)); } _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('SearchEnsureSOD');function SB420AF5B_Submit() 
.
.
. 
{ document.getElementById('ctl00_region_header_region_headerLinks_helpAreaID_ctl00_ctl00_SB420AF5B_InputKeywords').value=''; }}
// -->
</script>
```

This is normal tag item and there is no problem with it.

```
{'tag': 'div', 'unqid': '.....', 'id': 'newsContent0'}
```

But with the javascript tag I am getting error

```
{'text': 'IK F uu ph---------------------', 'tag': <cyfunction Comment at 0x00000000027A79A0>, 'unqid': '.....'}
```

This is my code:

```
ac = requests.get(url)
html_text = ac.text
lx = html.fromstring(html_text)
...some parsing codes

json.dumps(items).decode('utf-8') --> where I am getting error
```

Error is below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main3.py", line 132, in <module>
    PageRunner(url)
  File "main3.py", line 122, in PageRunner
    InsertPageTags(1, url)
  File "main3.py", line 58, in InsertPageTags
    parameter = (WebsiteID, Url, json.dumps(items).decode('utf-8'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <cyfunction Comment at 0x00000000029279A0> is not JSON serializable
```

How can I dump the html with comments or remove comments from html?

Comment: Remove comments? just take out the <!-- tags.

Comment: @Halislus -- what is the url and some more of your parsing code, so that I can test a working example for the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using javascript like in the previous answer, you can use a function using regex in Python:

```
import re

def js_comment_clean(js):
    js = re.sub("<!--[\\s\\S]*?(?:-->)?","",js)
    js = re.sub("<!--[\\s\\S]*?-->?","",js)
    js = re.sub('<!---+>?','',js)
    js = re.sub("|<!(?![dD][oO][cC][tT][yY][pP][eE]|\\[CDATA\\[)[^>]*>?","",js)
    js = re.sub("|<[?][^>]*>?","",js)
    return js
```

So, change your original line:

```
html_text = ac.text
```

with

```
html_text = js_comment_clean(ac.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the python json decoder doesn't know what to do with the `<cyfunction ...>` so it raises an error with that. You will need to write a customized json decoder: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.

Or perhaps if you know all tags are in the form of `<some_text>`, then you can first do a regex replace with an empty string or something where you know it will work. Taking the regex from this answer here ([Remove HTML comments with Regex, in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653207/remove-html-comments-with-regex-in-javascript)), it would be:

```
var COMMENT_PSEUDO_COMMENT_OR_LT_BANG = new RegExp(
'<!--[\\s\\S]*?(?:-->)?'
+ '<!---+>?'  // A comment with no body
+ '|<!(?![dD][oO][cC][tT][yY][pP][eE]|\\[CDATA\\[)[^>]*>?'
+ '|<[?][^>]*>?',  // A pseudo-comment
'g');
```