# How can you hide a div when CSS is disabled?

Tags: css, html, hidden

Here is the scenario: I have a div which I pre-load into a page and automatically set it's display property to hidden.  I use javascript to pop-up said div.  The issue is when clients have CSS disabled they can see the DIV, obviously.  What is the best way to have the div (or contents of the div) display only when my javascript function is called?

The best way I could think of is passing the raw HTML to a javascript var and then loading all the HTML using javascript, however, this is a bit slow(theres a decent amount of HTML) which causes the script to break when it tries to reference DIVs that do not exist yet.

any other more elegant solutions?

Thanks

Comment: What are the chances that a user who chooses not to apply author styling will permit author scripting? :-)

Comment: What do you mean CSS disabled? Having Javascript disabled happens, but CSS disabled isn't common... Could you explain?

Comment: @Kerrek: Thts the exact thing that popped as I was reading the question.. :)

Comment: Do you really need to support browsers without CSS? Even terminal browser like Lynx or Links support basic CSS like "display".

Comment: I wouldn't care about people with CSS disabled, they are already missing most part of the web and they probably have JS disabled too. Anyway @timaschew's solution is the logical way to do it.

Comment: @caffein: Disabling author CSS is one of my mainstay daily habits, *especially* when browsing content generated by people who ask these kinds of questions!

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap html comment tags around it:

```
<!-- <div>your stuff, which should be invisible</div> -->
```

Or remove it completely from the DOM

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/html-comments
[Maybe, here some related stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364601/is-it-possible-to-remove-an-html-comment-from-dom-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

If CSS is disabled, then the only way to hide the div is to remove it from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an inline style on the div (not recommended but your case is an exception anyway).

You can use JS/jQuery on page load to hide the `div` but it'll cause the flicker effect (`div` wiil be visible momentarily until the JS runs to hide it).

Comment: I think different browsers will react differently. A safer bet would be trying out @timaschew suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a div on your page when the page loads so that users without javascript can see it, perhaps to indicate them that some of the site functionalities require JS to work.

If you need to use that div exclusively with JS then having it already on the page is a bad approach imho. You should create it on the fly, at least the content.

This way you will ensure users without CSS won't see it, while still being able to show it for the rest of the people with JS enabled.

Answer (score -2):

Set the height of the div you wanna hide to zero using javascript.

> $('#mydiv').css("height", "0px");