# Removing HTML comments from DOM

Tags: php, javascript, html, comments

So basically, what im trying to achieve is output data via php within html comments and so it is not rendered.
Then use javascript to remove the comments so it is rendered on screen but in view page source, comments must be still there.

I tried a few solutions mentioned on other stackoverflow posts but nothing did the trick.
Any ideas anyone?

For example: if you view the source code of facebook, their content is in comments but yet its rendered.

```
    <script>big_pipe.onPageletArrive({"phase":1,"id":"pagelet_composer","css":["sbVQp"],"bootloadable":{"legacy:Composer":{"resources":["Q6HMA","sbVQp"]},"legacy:DataSource":{"resources":["Q6HMA"]},"legacy:dom":{"resources":["Q6HMA"]},"legacy:control-textarea":{"resources":["Q6HMA","IRaZg","sbVQp"]}},"resource_map":{"IRaZg":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yM\/r\/pc-N6ldw6Ia.js"}},"js":["Q6HMA"],"jscc_map":"({\"j98xJNAPg55OWGAly21\":function(){return new DataSource({\"maxResults\":5,\"queryData\":{\"viewer\":100003192277539,\"filter\":[\"page\",\"app\"],\"context\":\"topics\",\"rsp\":\"mentions\"},\"queryEndpoint\":\"\\\/ajax\\\/typeahead\\\/search.php\",\"bootstrapData\":{\"viewer\":100003192277539,\"filter\":[\"user\",\"friendlist\",\"page\",\"app\",\"group\",\"event\"],\"options\":[\"friends_only\",\"nm\",\"include_subscribed_lists\"],\"token\":\"v7\",\"context\":\"mentions\",\"rsp\":\"mentions\"},\"bootstrapEndpoint\":\"\\\/ajax\\\/typeahead\\\/first_degree.php\",\"token\":\"1332238929-7\"});},\"j98xJNAPg55OWGAly22\":function(){return new Composer($(\"uwgh9l_7\"), {\"xhpc\":\"composerTourStart\",\"endpoint\":\"\\\/ajax\\\/updatestatus.php\",\"formType\":1,\"placeholder\":\"What's on your mind?\",\"buttonLabel\":\"Post\",\"autoscrape\":true,\"barContent\":\"\\u003Cspan class=\\\"uiComposerTagControls friendTaggerIcon\\\">\\u003C\\\/span>\\u003Cspan class=\\\"uiComposerTagControls placeTaggerIcon\\\">\\u003C\\\/span>\",\"disableCache\":true,\"lazyEndpoint\":\"\\\/ajax\\\/metacomposer\\\/attachment\\\/status\\\/status.php\"}, true, JSCC.get('j98xJNAPg55OWGAly21'));},\"j98xJNAPg55OWGAly23\":function(){return new MentionsInput($(\"uwgh9l_8\"));},\"j98xJNAPg55OWGAly24\":function(){return new MetaComposerMessageBox();},\"j98xJNAPg55OWGAly25\":function(){return new TypeaheadMetrics({\"extraData\":{\"event_name\":\"mentions\"}});},\"j98xJNAPg55OWGAly26\":function(){return new Typeahead(JSCC.get('j98xJNAPg55OWGAly21'), {node_id: \"\", ctor: \"ContextualTypeaheadView\", options: {\"autoSelect\":true,\"renderer\":\"compact\"}}, {ctor: \"TypeaheadAreaCore\", options: {}}, $(\"uwgh9l_12\"))}})","onload":["JSCC.get('j98xJNAPg55OWGAly22').init(JSCC.get('j98xJNAPg55OWGAly23'));","JSCC.get('j98xJNAPg55OWGAly24').init($(\"uwgh9l_11\"), JSCC.get('j98xJNAPg55OWGAly23'));"],"content":{"pagelet_composer":{"container_id":"uwgh9l_14"}}});</script>



<code class="hidden_elem" id="uwgh9l_15"><!-- <ul id="boulder_fixed_header" class="uiStream"><li class="mts uiStreamHeader"><span class="plm uiStreamHeaderText fss fwb"></span><div class="uiStreamHeaderChronologicalForm"><div class="uiSelector inlineBlock uiSelectorRight uiSelectorNormal uiSelectorDynamicLabel"><div class="wrap"><a class="uiSelectorButton uiButton" role="button" href="#" aria-haspopup="1" data-length="30" rel="toggle"><span class="uiButtonText">SORT</span></a><div class="uiSelectorMenuWrapper uiToggleFlyout"><div role="menu" class="uiMenu uiSelectorMenu"><ul class="uiMenuInner"><li class="uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption checked" data-label="SORT"><a class="itemAnchor" role="menuitemradio" tabindex="0" aria-checked="true" href="/?sk=h_nor"><span class="itemLabel fsm">Top Stories</span></a></li><li class="uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption" data-label="SORT: MOST RECENT"><a class="itemAnchor" role="menuitemradio" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="false" href="/?sk=h_chr"><span class="itemLabel fsm">Most Recent</span></a></li></ul></div></div></div><select><option value=""></option><option value="h_nor" selected="1">SORT</option><option value="h_chr">SORT: MOST RECENT</option></select></div></div></li></ul><div id="pagelet_stream_masher" data-referrer="pagelet_stream_masher"></div><div class="UIIntentionalStream UIStream"  id="c4f68733a3e65c9c49002913"><ul class="uiList uiStream uiStreamHomepage translateParent UIIntentionalStream_Content" id="home_stream"></ul><div ><div class="UIIntentionalStream_Error"><div class="pam uiBoxRed"><div class="fsl fwb fcb">This stream is unavailable at this time. Please try again soon.</div></div></div></div><div ><div id="pagelet_stream_pager"></div></div></div> --></code>
```

They use a system called bigpipe for realtime and faster interface but i dont want to use a realtime system(not for now).
So im trying to do the same thing!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Comments aren't rendered anyway, are they?

Comment: By 'rendered', do you mean 'part of the HTML sent to the client'?

Comment: Don't. Seriously. Find another way to store the data.

Comment: could you provide a demo link?

Comment: why don't you use `.hidden { display: none; }` + `<div class="hidden"><?php ...`

Comment: comments have a nodetype of 8, i read here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364601/is-it-possible-to-remove-an-html-comment-from-dom-using-jquery

One user provided a snippet but it does not work.

Comment: Have you try regex such a preg_replace() to remove the comment on the fly as you displaying.

Comment: "View Source" will (in all browsers I use) show the source as it was sent from the web server, so you don't have to worry about that part. If you want something to start hidden and then be displayed it would be more usual to use CSS to set it as `display:none` and then change the `display` style with JS as appropriate.

Comment: well what im trying to do is, some might find it stupid but this will stop amateurs from stealing my html, they are gonna see some comments and will most probably ignore it..
So thats why im looking for this rather than display: none;
also @Churk preg_replace is a php function, that would render into view source removing the comments, i want view source to have the comments

Comment: Another way to look at this is to ask why you think amateurs would want to steal your html? Is it _that_ good? (Mine isn't.) If you're determined to go ahead, why not load your content with Ajax? Then it won't appear in the "View Source" at all. (Though that still won't stop savvy users from getting access to it.)

Comment: @MarshallMathews Well, I updated my answer too... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Locate element that holds comments ( E.g. by using `document.getElementBydId`), and do this for extracting content within comments:

```
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/<!--((.|\n|\r)*?)-->/g, '$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

simple use css and set it to `display:none;` or `visibility : hidden;`
if it's for seo purposes there's an article that can be read here
http://3n9.org/articles/css-hiding.html

and tbh i really dont understand what your asking for ... since comment already doesnt get rendered onscreen so i assumme you want to hide html onload

Comment: not exactly what im looking for, but thanks :)
I will end up using it if i dont find another way

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the "commented" code in a div... and toggle visibility (as posted below) :

```
function toggleVisibility(var v)
{
    var vis="hidden";

    if (v) vis="visible";

    document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.visibility = vis;
}
```

Comment: im updating the question with an example, check it out!

Answer (score -2):

You will have to get all nodes from the page and then cycle through them looking for nodeType.  Check for comments and then use the removeChild property on the nodes parent.

Comment: You dont have ID on comment `<!-- this is an html comment -->`

Comment: @Churk I already altered my comment before you posted your response.