# jQuery comment/uncomment <!--element-->

Tags: javascript, jquery, comments, element

I am looking for a way to wrap, with jQuery, an element into a comment, like:

```
<!--
<div class="my_element"></div>
-->
```

and also a way to remove the comments.

Is this possible?

Comment: It'd be useful to know what your use case is. I can't think of many situations where this is the right thing to do, rather than either hiding the element, or removing it from the DOM and adding it back later.

Comment: I've never seen something like that :) consider hiding it, the result is the same. Hidden from the screen, but visible on source code, same result.

Comment: I can't hide it, because I use some jquery plugin, similar to masonry, that is unhiding it back.

Comment: I think more fundementally, you need to hide from **view** using javascript (eg jQuery.hide(el)) - hiding from "source" is impossible.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the question that SO is saying it is. This one asks about uncommenting/commenting as opposed to the related question, which is about removing the comment node. Also, a valid use case that I've had is a quick and easy way to detach and stop video elements on a JSPA to speed up performance in IE 8.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To wrap an element with comment, or more specifically to replace an element with a comment node having that element's HTML:

```
my_element_jq = $('.my_element');
comment = document.createComment(my_element_jq.get(0).outerHTML);
my_element_jq.replaceWith(comment);
```

To switch it back:

```
$(comment).replaceWith(comment.nodeValue);
```

If you don't have the reference to the comment node then you need to traverse the DOM tree and check `nodeType` of each node. If its value is 8 then it is a comment.

For example:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div>bar</div>
    <!-- <div>hello world!</div> -->
    <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// .contents() returns the children of each element in the set of matched elements,
// including text and comment nodes.
$("#foo").contents().each(function(index, node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 8) {
        // node is a comment
        $(node).replaceWith(node.nodeValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can comment the element out by doing the following:

```
function comment(element){
    element.wrap(function() {
        return '<!--' + this.outerHTML + '"-->';
    });
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/THBpD/27/

Comment: this.outerHTML should be enough, don't need $()

Answer (score 2):

I'm impresed nobody gave the following solution. The following solution require a container. This container will have inside, the commented / uncommented code.

```
function comment(element) {
    element.html('<!--' + element.html() + '-->')
}

function uncomment(element) {
    element.html(element.html().substring(4, element.html().length - 3))
}

function isCommented(element) {
    return element.html().substring(0, 4) == '<!--';
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ConsoleTVs/r6bm5nhz/

Answer (score -2):

For wrapping?

```
function wrap(jQueryElement){
    jQueryElement.before("<!--").after("-->");
}
```

Not sure how successful you'd be finding the comments once wrapped though. A text search on the body element using regular expressions is an option.

Or this - [is it possible to remove an html comment from dom using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364601/is-it-possible-to-remove-an-html-comment-from-dom-using-jquery)

Comment: this doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/zjjBE/ it treats the first one as both an open and close, and the 2nd as a string.

Comment: Fair enough. Stoopid question anyway ;)