# jQuery wrap with html comment tags

Tags: jquery, comments

I already tried 3 solution but didn't work.

I want to wrap my sidebar with comment tags.

First solution:

```
$("#sidebar").wrap("<!--googleoff: index--><!--googleon: index>");
```

Second solution:

From this post: [jQuery comment/uncomment <!--element-->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553531/jquery-comment-uncomment-element)

```
function comment(element){
    element.wrap(function() {
        alert(this.outerHTML);
        return '<!--googleoff: index-->'+this.outerHTML+'"<!--googleon: index>';
    });
}
comment($('#sidebar'));
```

Third solution:

```
$('#sidebar').prepend("<!--googleoff: index-->");
$('#sidebar').append("<!--googleon: index>");
```

the result I want:

```
<!--googleoff: index--> //start comment tags
 <div id="sidebar"></div>
<!--googleon: index> // tags
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('#sidebar').before("<!--googleoff: index-->");
$('#sidebar').after("<!--googleon: index-->");
```

Comment: it didn't work. When I view source I can't find the comment tags.

Comment: If you using chrome, mouse right click then "Inspect Element" not "View Page Source". Page Source means loaded Dom Element, not Current Dom Element