# Jquery uncomment the second child inside head tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two comment tag inside the head tag. I want to uncomment the second comment only.

```
var x = "<html><head><!-- <#if> I don't want any change </#if> --><!-- <#if>I want to uncomment </#if> --></head></html>";

$(x).contents().each(function(index, node) {
     if (node.nodeType == 8) {
        $(node[0]).replaceWith(node.nodeValue);
    }
});

alert(x);
```

Output should be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- <#if> I don't want any change </#if> -->
    <#if> I want to uncomment </#if>
<head>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? To me, trying to edit the page header after the page has already loaded is most likely not the best approach to whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: This sounds like xy-problem, what do you have in the comment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553531/jquery-comment-uncomment-element)

Comment: Making changes to the DOM in `$(x)` doesn't modify the original string. You need to do something like `dom = $(x)`, then use `dom.contents()`, and finally `alert(dom.html())`

Comment: `var parts = x.split("<!-- ");
parts[2]=parts[2].replace(" -->","");
parts[1] = "<!-- " + parts[1];
console.log(parts.join(""));`

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Actually it's a simple string replacement application. User will put entire html code into input box and hit process button. it will convert the code and give the output. But i got stucked in this situation. Any idea ?

Comment: @mplungjan but i want only the second child to be uncomment. Rest thing will be unchanged.

Comment: Ah, so it's for modifying HTML before they're actually served? That makes more sense. Can you give us a general rule for which portion you are trying to change? Is it always the second one out of two?

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Exactly ! Yes it is always the second one out of two inside the HEAD section.

Comment: My code does exactly what you ask. Uncomment  second comment only

Comment: @mplungjan Add that as an answer; your solution works when I try it.

Comment: @mplungjan  That works, but i need to target inside the HEAD tag only. Because there are lot of comments above the HEAD and rest part of the document. Hope it's making any sense.

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML;

var parts = x.split("<!-- "); 
parts[2]=parts[2].replace(" -->",""); 
parts[1] = "<!-- " + parts[1]; 
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML=parts.join("");
```

Comment: 'x' contains the html string. Is it possible to target head tag from the variable x and do the stuff ?

Comment: Just use your string instead of my first statement