# How can I show/hide a bootstrap spinner with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show a bootstrap spinner after a click on a button and then hide it after getting a response from an API (basically a loading status).

My button is as follow:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <button type="button" name="btn-enviar" class="btn btn-primary w-100">
    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-3" id="spinner" role="status" aria-hidden="true">
    </span>Enviar</button>
</div>
```

So far I've tried to comment/uncomment my span tag with no luck, there would be an easier way to start/stop my spinner?

My comment/uncomment functions which I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553531/jquery-comment-uncomment-element) and are not working (as requested):

```
function comment(element) {
    element.html('<!--' + element.html() + '-->')
}

function uncomment(element) {
    element.html(element.html().substring(4, element.html().length - 3))
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your javascript or jquery code here as well.

Comment: Use a css classnames to hide and show spinner.

Comment: @Codebeat I tried to do so with $('#spinner]').hide(); and $('#spinner]').show();, and it doesn't work

Comment: CSS: #spinner { display:none; } body.spin #spinner { display:block; } In onclick event: $('body').addClass('spin'); When done: $('body').removeClass('spin'); Don't use .html() to hide/recreate element, it is stress to the DOM and can introduce ugly side effects. So better do it with CSS classes, it is easier and less stressful.

Comment: Also, check your html is valid and complete with html validator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Html (with added class .spinner):

```
<div class="col-6">
    <button type="button" name="btn-enviar" class="btn btn-primary w-100">
    <span class="spinner spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-3" id="spinner" role="status" aria-hidden="true">
    </span>Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Add css to css-file:

```
#spinner { display:none; } 
body.busy .spinner { display:block !important; }
```

Or use visibility:

```
#spinner { visibility:hidden; } 
body.busy .spinner { visibility:visible !important; }
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
  $('#spinner').on('click', function()
  {
    $('body').addClass('busy');
  });
});
```

When done, do:

```
$('body').removeClass('busy');
```

With a class like 'busy' added to the body of the html page, you can also do very nice things like blocking input elements and such without extra js code. Let CSS do all the work for you instead of js. You only have to add some extra CSS rules.

PS: Check your html for errors with html validator. If there are errors in the markup, strange things might happen or it doesn't work.

Have fun.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this isn't on any bootstrap spinner page? Everything about how to make it look cool, nothing about how to show/hide

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, my guess is because it can be achieved the usual way; it doesn't really require a special treatment.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils This is not a special treatment at all. Very basic stuff, clean, easy to maintain and to avoid messy code soup.

Comment: I'm referring to why bootstrap would not want to get into the business of describing how you show and hide things in a browser - specifically not on the "spinner page." Then, you'll have to put it on the cards page and so on. And if they put it somewhere central, they might as well send you to one of the other many resources that already deal with it.

Comment: Bootstrap 5 users; spinners are not identified by `spinner` class anymore. Therefore, to match the CSS of this answer, you may want to fetch the `#spinner` ID with following CSS instead:

```css
body.busy #spinner {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Thank you for the answer, Codebeat.

Answer (score 5):

There are `animation` and `-webkit-animation` css attributes on the element.

Use a class like this

```
.stop {
 animation-name: none !important;
 -webkit-animation-name: none !important;
}
```

With JQuery you can toggle this class on the element. If it is added, the animation will stop.

**Update**
This will show then hide the spinner.

```js
$(() => {
  $('button').on('click', e => {
    let spinner = $(e.currentTarget).find('span')
    spinner.removeClass('d-none')
    setTimeout(_ => spinner.addClass('d-none'), 2000)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/spinners/">

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
  <span class="d-none spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  Click me...
</button>
```

Comment: I tried your code, it only prevented the spinner from spinning. I need to completely show/remove it from screen based on action.

Comment: @RogerioSchmitt yes, that is what it does, as you wrote, you want to _start/stop your spinner_ But that is something else. Let me see..

Comment: @ZogoZ Sorry, I edited my question for a better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

I just faced the same problem and solved it with `visibility` style attribute.

HTML:

```
<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" id="spinner" style="visibility: hidden"></span>
```

JS:

```
let spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");
spinner.style.visibility = 'visible'; //'hidden'
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#spin_ID").attr('hidden', true);// Hide

$("#spin_ID").attr('hidden', false);// Show

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me Bootstrap 5.2.3

HTML

```
<style>
    #spinner { display:none; } 
    body.spin #spinner { display:block; }
</style>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="spinner-border" role="status" id="spinner">
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('body').addClass('spin');
do_something ();
$('body').removeClass('spin');
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't get your code exactly but I am putting my idea, you can try if feasible.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#spinner").spinner({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      $('#d1').html("Spinner has started ");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $('#d1').html("Spinner has stopped ");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<input id="spinner" class='selector' value=12 size=3>
<div id=d1></div>
```