# Display progress image / spinner in ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on converting a legacy application to ASP.NET Core MVC. I have a long running process which returns data only after 15 seconds. I have done all methods to optimise the backend procedure including adding custom paging but could not reduce the execution time any further.

On the click of the process button, a procedure is executed to insert data and then return data based on the filter parameters. I want to display a progress image in the view so that the user gets to know about the data processing operation. The process button is present in a modal popup in the view.

This is my view :

```
<form class="mt-4" id="myform" name="myform" asp-controller="Process" asp-action="YearEndProcess" method="post">
 <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
    <!-- Modal title -->
    <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900" id="modal-title">Year End Processing</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
        <!-- Select Year -->
        <div>
            <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt text-blue-600 mr-1"></i> PROC YEAR
            </label>            
            <select id="procYrDropdown" asp-for="SelectedProcYear" required class="form-control w-full mt-1">
                <option value="">Select Proc Yr</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="SelectedProcYear" class="text-danger field-validation-valid"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- Select Month -->
        <div>
            <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                <i class="fas fa-calendar-check text-green-600 mr-1"></i> PROC MONTH
            </label>
            <select class="form-control w-full mt-1" id="procMonthDropdown" required asp-for="SelectedProcMonth">
                <option value="">Select Proc Month</option>                   
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="SelectedProcMonth" class="text-danger field-validation-valid"></span>
        </div>           
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal footer -->
<div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
    <button type="submit" value="process"
        class="w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent px-4 py-2  text-base font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm"
        style="background-color: #5000bb;">
        @*onclick="showProcessingModal()"*@           
    </button>
    <button type="button"
        class="mt-3 w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm"
        onclick="hideModal()">
        Cancel
    </button>
</div>
```

This is my controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> YearEndProcess(ProcessingViewModel processData)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    YearEndProcessBAL yearEndProcessBAL = new(_configuration);
    result re = new();
    try
    {
    re = await yearEndProcessBAL.Process(processData);    
    processData.processedData = await yearEndProcessBAL.getProcessedData(processData, 1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    _logger.LogError("Error occured during processing.", processData);
    }
    }
    return View("YearEndProcess", processData);
    }
```

I am new to .NET Core. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: **This is a surprisingly difficult thing to implement**, so you know you'll need to AJAX / `fetch` for that, right? Are you familiar with all the (very wildly different) approaches for obtaining progress information from SQL Server? (I assume you're using SQL Server, but your post doesn't say), and you're maintaining a list of ongoing operations in-memory? (Also, it's entirely possible that your procedure to insert data is very inefficient (and are you doing RBAR INSERT, batch INSERT, BULK INSERT, or something else?) so if you can make your inserts _fast_ then you won't need to show progress.

Comment: I am using an Oracle procedure to insert and retrieve data. I am not doing any in-memory operations. Apart from this page, I have few other pages to display progress bar till the data gets rendered in the view. Kindly send sample code to do the same using AJAX

Comment: As mentioned an actual progress bar is incredibly hard.  Especially with a traditional http request/response. If you just want a "spinner" or some other indicator of a long running process that doesn't actually indicate progress , that is much easier.

Comment: I am working on changing the front end for a legacy application to Dot Net Core MVC, I cannot do any changes that will alter the existing DB or table structure. I have done all possible ways to improve the performance of the procedure in back end. It is working on processing large volume of data.

Comment: A spinner will also be sufficient to indicate that a long running process is been executed. so that the user does not close the page. Kindly send some sample code since this is an urgent requirement to be completed ASAP.  I have completed rest of the functionalities in the page other than this.

Comment: _"Kindly send some sample code since this is an urgent requirement"_ - That's not how StackOverflow works, sorry. You can't just expect us to do your job for you - and saying "it's urgent" without being reasonable (e.g., explaining that it's for charity or a good cause when it's actually for business-system that you're being paid to write (I assume) reeks of arrogance). So, _kindly reassess your priors_, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple solution to display a spinner image using a partial view and a simple JavaScript function.

Create a partial view named '_LoadingPartial' with the bootstrap spinner as shown below. (Other spinners / progress images can also be used instead of the bootstrap spinner.)

```
@{ 
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="spinner-border text-primary mb-3"
             style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem; display: none"
             role="status" id="loading">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div> 
 }
```

Place the partial view tag in the place where the spinner is intended to be displayed. (I have placed it under the 'process' button)

```
<partial name="_LoadingPartial" />
```

I have called the below javascript function in the view page on the 'process' button click event.

```
 function displayProcessingImage()() {           
        if (document.getElementById("procYrDropdown").value != ""
            && document.getElementById("procMonthDropdown").value != "") {
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

The processing image spins gracefully along with 'loading' text when the process button is clicked and hides after the process completes.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a progress bar using [JQuery UI](https://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/) or [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/), and you can make an AJAX call using [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Unless you know that the server side code will execute in exactly a specific time such as 15 seconds, it wouldn't make sense to show progress in the progress bar based on time. To show a more accurate progress of the request, you will need to expose an endpoint on the server side to provide a percentage completion of the original request, or use SignalR/WebSockets. On the other hand, if you simply want to inform the user that the request is being processed, you could show an indeterminate progress bar. But then again, in this case, you could consider showing a simple spinner control instead.

Comment: The links above show the sample code to use AJAX with jQuery and to display the progress bar with Bootstrap. If a simple spinner control is good enough, this answer shows the sample code, again using jQuery and Bootstrap: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476628/2457113

Comment: The spinner image can be displayed on 'process' button click but how to hide it after the data is loaded? Should I make an AJAX call to get the response instead of calling the controller action method directly?

Comment: Yes, make an AJAX call to the URL of the controller's action method. After the data is loaded, use the done function in the jQuery $.ajax call to hide the spinner.