# How to remove an HTML comment with Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, comments

I'm having some difficulty removing comments from an XML file.

[I have already looked into this post, but it doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364601/is-it-possible-to-remove-an-html-comment-from-dom-using-jquery)

I have a structure like this:

```
<root>
 <!--space -->
  <space>
    <content/>
 </space>
 <!--Time -->
 <time>
    <content/>
 </time>
<root/>
```

This exists in my code as an xmldocument using jquery parseXML.
Now, if I want to delete the "time" tag, I also want to delete the preceding "time" comment. I understand that to select this comment, I need to use the "contains()" function on the root element to list both tags and comments. Then once found, I should simply need to use "remove()" to remove it from my xmldocument. 
The problem is that it doesn't work. I find the content, I use "remove()", it doesn't return any error, everything seems fine, but I can still select it.

So I do something like this:

```
var allTagsAndComments = $(XML.firstChild).contents();
```

I see it lists a comment as the first element in the collection. Then I test in the console, by entering:

```
allTagsAndComments[0].remove();
```

No, error, but the comment is still there. 
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like the mystery has been solved.

When I do the "remove()", it doesn't update the "contents()"-collection, but it does update the xmldocument. So if I run the "contents()" again after removal, it will display the expected elements.