# JQuery. Parse XML children recursively. How?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have been trying to find an example on how to go about parsing the following XML document. The sample below shows how much depth I am looking at.

I think I need the following:

**1. A function to load the XML.**

```
$.get('getProfile.xml', null, function (data) {
    // ...
}, 'xml');
```

**2. A way to loop through root node looking for child nodes. For each child node found, loop through found child node's children looking for new children of children. If none found, just simply output what's inside this child node.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetProfile>
    <UserInfo>
        <id>free2rhyme</id>
        <name>jerry mcguire</name>
        <age>29</age>
        <sex>m</sex>
        <location>salt lake city, utah</location>
        <signup>00/00/0000</signup>
    </UserInfo>
    <Entry>
        <id>13579</id>
        <date>2011-01-24</date>
        <time>9:34:21</time>
        <title>my first jounal entry</title>
        <body>&lt;![CDATA[i'm really excited to have signed up for myjournal.co.cc! Yes!!!]]&gt;</body>
        <Comments>
            <Comment>
                <id>97531</id>
                <date>2011-02-16</date>
                <time>9:34:21</time>
                <from>otheruser84</from>
                <body>I am glad you really liked the site! Have fun!!</body>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
                <id>97531</id>
                <date>2011-02-16</date>
                <time>9:34:21</time>
                <from>otheruser84</from>
                <body>I am glad you really liked the site! Have fun!!</body>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
                <id>97531</id>
                <date>2011-02-16</date>
                <time>9:34:21</time>
                <from>otheruser84</from>
                <body>I am glad you really liked the site! Have fun!!</body>
            </Comment>
        </Comments>
    </Entry>
    <Stats>
        <following>40</following>
        <followers>57</followers>
        <entries>158</entries>
        <favorites>15</favorites>
    </Stats>
    <Preview>
        <Entries>
            <Entry>
                <id>97531</id>
                <date>2011-02-16</date>
                <time>9:34:21</time>
                <title>otheruser84</title>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <id>97531</id>
                <date>2011-02-16</date>
                <time>9:34:21</time>
                <title>otheruser84</title>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <id>97531</id>
                <date>2011-02-16</date>
                <time>9:34:21</time>
                <title>otheruser84</title>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <id>97531</id>
                <date>2011-02-16</date>
                <time>9:34:21</time>
                <title>otheruser84</title>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <id>97531</id>
                <date>2011-02-16</date>
                <time>9:34:21</time>
                <title>otheruser84</title>
            </Entry>
        </Entries>
    </Preview>
</GetProfile>
```

**3. The sample above hopefully clarifies what I am trying to do.**

**4. Here's a way to return the node's index, name and value however it does not check for child nodes that may also have children of their own.**

```
var getProfile = $(data).find('GetProfile').each(function () {

    $('*', this).each(function (index, event) {
        alert('index=' + index + ' name=' + e.tagName + ' value=' + $(e).text());
    });

});
```

Comment: if you are not sending data to server then you don't need to pass NULL in second parameter. Just omit it.

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to do. Can you add an example of the expected output given the sample input?

Comment: for now I just want to build a <ul> <li> structure of it. I'll make it look pretty later.

Comment: The latest edit I made to the original post includes a way to get the nodes by index which would keep me from editing the code should an update come up.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/11866/1954) provides a snippet to recursively traverse an XML DOM:

```
function traverse(tree) {
    if (tree.hasChildNodes()) {
        document.write('<ul><li>');
        document.write('<b>' + tree.tagName + ' : </b>');
        var nodes = tree.childNodes.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < tree.childNodes.length; i++)
        traverse(tree.childNodes(i));
        document.write('</li></ul>');
    } else document.write(tree.text);
}
```

Another way is to use a DOM parser (e.g. `window.DOMParser` or `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")`) to parse an XML string:

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
} 
else { // Internet Explorer
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
}
```

See this page: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp.

---

**Edit**:

```
function traverse(tree) {
    $(tree).contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType == 3) { // text node
            // node value: $(this).text() or this.nodeValue
            console.log('text node value: '+ $(this).text());

        } else {
            console.log('tag name: ' + this.nodeName);
            traverse(this);
        }
    });
}
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/uKGHJ/1/.

Comment: Old school sample. I'm using JQuery. Yes I could adapt but that is also the question. I'm not really sure how. =)

Comment: You can easily modify the first snippet to do what you want, using some of the traversing methods  in jQuery... (http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: Thank you. It seems I can only return the first root node using contents(). If I use children() I can return all nodes but only tag names. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be a small bug: `this.text()`. I updated the answer and included a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: instead of using `this.nodeType == 3`, I think it would be nicer to use `this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE`, see [Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType).

Comment: @Sk8erPeter nice suggestion! I'd love to avoid magic numbers wherever possible, but that might not play well within IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423599/node-text-node-and-ie7.

Comment: @WilliamNiu: oh, I'm sorry, you're right. :( I forgot about the stupidities of IE. In this case, the suggestion to define an own Node constant would be correct. (But I know this would be a little bit extreme to do it in this short code. :) ) Another suggestion: to keep this code really jQuery-like, you could also use `$(this).prop('nodeType')` instead of `this.nodeType`, but it's just a quiet comment and another possibility. :) (and maybe unnecessary)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this .

```
$(xml).find("Entry").each(function () {  

    alert($(this).find("id").text())

    $(this).find("Comments").each(function () {
        $(this).find("Comment").each(function () {
            alert($(this).find("id").text())
            alert($(this).find("date").text())
            alert($(this).find("time").text())
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a cool example. I just wanted to make it so that the code looks for children of children while not necessarily knowing their names in advance.