# How do I use jQuery to select an element that directly contains some specified text?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, contains

The jQuery selector `:contains(text)` selects an element if the matching text appears directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof.
I want to select an element if and only if the matching text appears directly within the selected element. What should I do?

For example,

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">
       <a><img src="la.gif"></a>
       happy birthday 
       <ul><li>radom</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li id="2">
       <a><img src="la.gif"></a>
       sad 
       <ul><li>happy</li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to select the `li` that contains the word "happy" (don't select a `li` if only its descendant contains the word "happy"). Then only `li#1` should be selected.

The following does NOT do what I want because it will select both `li#1` and `li#2`:

```
$('li:contains("happy")');
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7896669/830125

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector for an element that directly contains text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896455/jquery-selector-for-an-element-that-directly-contains-text)

Comment: Having any content in a `ul` or `ol` other than a `li` is invalid HTML.

Comment: Sorry guys I gave bad html examples. Fixed it. Please check out the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: @user1031868 Can you tell us what is the expected output for the above markup?

Comment: @SKS, I want to select li#1 (since it's a li that directly contains "happy") and add a class to it.

Comment: @user1031868 I think I understood now, Please check the edits and the demo.. let me know if that is something you want. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/HwB9D/7/

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** As from your updated code, I think you need to use `.contents()` and check for `nodeType` to make sure it is a text node and then compare it to the text as you need.

```
$('ul li').contents().each( function () {
    if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.nodeValue.match(/happy/)) {
        $(this).closest('li').css('border', '1px solid red');
    }
});
```

or using `.filter()`,

```
$('ul li').contents().filter( function () {
    if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.nodeValue.match(/happy/)) {
         return true;       
    }
}).closest('li').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/HwB9D/7/)

Let me know if this works..

---

`ul` should only contain `li` tags.. like below,

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">happy</li>
    <li id="2">sad <div>happy</div></li>
</ul>
```

Assuming your html like that, below is the script to get the first list,

```
$('ul li').filter (function () {
    if ($(this).text() == 'happy') return true;
});
```

`.filter` will return the `li` that has text 'happy'.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/HwB9D/4/)

Comment: @Niko Are you mentioning selecting '<ul id="1">happy</ul>'?  It can be done, but that is not a valid ul construct.

Comment: I gave a bad example. Please check out the updated question. My problem is if li has descendants that contains the specified text but li itself doesn't directly contains it, I do NOT want to select it.

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I mean, you're right about that. But what if the `<li>` contains a text like "happy birthday"? `:contains` would select this node, your filter won't.

Comment: $(this).text() will get the text of all desendents of the selected element. If the selected element has a child element and then the proper text, this would still return that element.

Comment: Hmm, I understand it in a different way: The node's text must *contain* the word, it does not need to be equivalent to it. And furthermore the filter must not select a node like `<li><span>happy</span></li>`. But you may be right.

Comment: @SKS, not exactly. The example I give is much more simplified than the actual code. So you may expect all li's has many descendants. I want to filter those who "directly contain" the specified text. KevinB and Niko's interpretations are right.

Comment: @user1031868 Just add an elseif to that as else if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) { .... } http://jsfiddle.net/skram/HwB9D/9/. I would just have a parent if as TEXT_NODE and inside that check for happy or not.

Comment: Hey, I know it sounds dumb, but i'm using a system which has a default <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />. I have no way to change it to IE9 standard, and the Node seems to be undefined in any standard lower than IE9. What should I do?

Comment: nvm. I found the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423599/node-text-node-and-ie7

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.filter()` for a more specific check:

```
alert(
    $("ul").filter(function(){return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "happy"})[0].id
);​
```

It checks the `nodeValue` of the first child node of each `ul` to see if it is a text node that contains "happy".